# What are Node.js style modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently reading about Browserify as I am deciding which would be better to use with Knockout.js developing a SPA. The article I am reading mentions:

> Browserify allows us to use node.js style modules in the browser

What does he mean with Node.js style modules? How is it different with regular JavaScript modules or jQuery modules?

Comment: If you put your exact question title to google you'd get the answer in the very first link.

Comment: @zerkms: It says CommonJS modules which I didn't think was the same with or would explain Node.js modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js-style modules have a [defined API](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Regular JavaScript modules doesn't really exist, although EcmaScript 6 will bring [a standard module format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

[jQuery modules](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) are little more than scripts which bind objects to the jQuery namespace and expect a jQuery object as `this` when they are called.